# Upgrading A Verizon Galaxy Note 2 to Marshmallow

Tags: rooting, 6.0-marshmallow, samsung-galaxy-note

I'd like to upgrade my old Verizon branded Samsung Galaxy Note 2 (SCH-I605) running 4.4.2 to Android Marshmallow to get the latest updates (specifically the security updates for StageFright), but thus far I haven't been able to find any documentation on the internet showing how. My Nexus 6 actually gets it's updates directly from Google thus guaranteeing I always have the latest patches.

I'm tech savvy, but I've never tried unlocking/rooting/modding a phone before. Can anyone provide any guidance on what tools to use and what ROM to install?

Note: I understand rooting/modding a phone comes with risks and accept full responsibility if I 'brick' my phone.

Comment: First step - root! Since 4.4.2 is still vulnerable to the kernel privilege elevation exploit, rooting takes literally 30 seconds. Just google towelroot.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you'll wanna use CyanogenMod. If so, then simply follow the official steps provided by the [community for your device.](https://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Install_CM_for_i605)

In the documentation in the above link, the tool called `heimdall` is mentioned. I will recommend it. I have used it several times with Samsung devices, and had 100% success (I'm on Linux)

If that is *not* your device, do *not* proceed with the steps in there.

If all goes well, you should be able to download updates from the [Download sections on CyanogenMod website](https://download.cyanogenmod.org/?device=i605).

Comment: Heimdall works like a charm indeed. Windows users have to go with ODIN though

Comment: @TheBro21 does heimdall not work with Windows? I see Windows listed in the supported OSs here: http://glassechidna.com.au/heimdall/